# Variable define on environment in GitHub seems not readable by actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I define environment in my GitHub repository, in Development environment I define variable `ENVIRONMENT_STAGE = dev`.

In my GitHub action I want to get this env var (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context) and it's doesn't work :

```
name: Deploy environment for PR

on:
  push:
    branches: [ development ]

jobs:
  test-env-var:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Show env var
        run: |
          echo "${{env.ENVIRONMENT_STAGE}}"
```

Result is :

```
Run echo ""
  echo ""
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
```

How can I get environment variables in GitHub Actions?

Comment: [`environment`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment) configuration is missing in your workflow.

Comment: PS: you had multiple spellings of the word `ENVIRONMENT`, make sure they're all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a few changes:

1. [Add the `environment: dev` to the job to have it include the variables defined in the environment on GitHub.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#using-an-environment)
2. [Reference the variable using the `vars.` scope](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values).
3. [Pass the variable into the environment block of the step](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-an-intermediate-environment-variable)
4. [Reference the variable using a standard environment variable in bash.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-an-intermediate-environment-variable)

Step 3 and 4 are optional, [but highly recommended from a security standpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).

```yaml
name: Deploy environnement for PR

on:
  push:
    branches: [ development ]

jobs:
  test-env-var:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev                 
    # ^
    # Add the environment to your job

    steps:
      - name: SHow env var
        run: |
          echo $ENVIRONMENT_STAGE    
        # ^ 
        # Reference by environment variable for added security
        

        env:
          ENVIRONMENT_STAGE = ${{ vars.ENVIRONMENT_STAGE }}
          # ^                        # ^
          # Pass the Github          # Reference the GitHub Environment's
          # environment variable     # variable using the vars 
          # to the step's            # context
          # environment
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, it's works well !! How can I dynamicly change "environment: dev" according to the branch on which I am located? I have three environement all three define ENVIRONEMENT_STAGE variable with different value

Comment: If I'm on development branch take  environment: dev but if I'm on staging branche  environment: staging

Comment: I really don't understand github action documentation, all the example workflow does'nt work ... workflow reference at this link litteraly doesn't work ... https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values

Comment: There's a few options, probably worth a seperate question. One is to change the workflow in the dev branch and set the value there hard coded.

Comment: Another option is to use an expression to set the value based on the branch name which is available from the GitHub context.